# Missing jade/pug syntax highlightning and settings in visual studio community 2022 version 17.6.5

Tags: pug, visual-studio-2022

I recently updated my visual studio community 2022 to the latest version (17.6.5)

Now when I open any .pug file in my project visual studio uses the default editor (Common Language Editor Supporting TextMate Bundles) instead of the actual pug/jade editor.

I tried this: [Jade like syntax highlighting of .pug files Visual Studio 2015](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37465114/jade-like-syntax-highlighting-of-pug-files-visual-studio-2015), but there is no jade editor available for me to select.

If I go to options and scroll down to Text Editor there is no option for jade either.

I tried reinstalling, rebooting, downloading the preview version. Nothing seems to add that editor that I used to have, and because I reinstalled, I can't go back to the previous version. I can't download it from here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releases/2022/release-history#updating-your-installation-to-a-specific-release because the download for community is only available in the most current version.

I looked through the visual studio installer individual components without any luck.

I searched the marketplace, the closest I could find was this https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MadsKristensen.SyntaxHighlightingPack which only support visual studio 2019.

I can run and compile the project just fine, its just the settings and highlightning that's missing.

Does anybody have an idea to what I can do to fix this? Is there something I need to toggle or install?

Please help. I need my highlightning :(

Update:
According to this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/adding-visual-studio-editor-support-for-other-languages?view=vs-2022 jade should be supported, so something is definitely off

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recently ran into the same exact issue and seemed to have solved it by creating a Textmate Grammar Template project in VS 2022 and creating an extension to support pug highlighting in VS 2022.

I have uploaded the extension to the VS marketplace and it can be found here: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=AlexanderRamesar.PugLanguage2022