# Pug syntax highlighting

Tags: visual-studio-2022

Migrated a Node.js project from VS2019 to VS2022 and I lost syntax highlighting for the .pug files.  I look in Tools -> Options -> Text Editor and it no longer has Jade/Pug in the list.  Is there something I can do to get syntax highlighting back for the .pug files?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Missing jade/pug syntax highlightning and settings in visual studio community 2022 version 17.6.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76829823/missing-jade-pug-syntax-highlightning-and-settings-in-visual-studio-community-20)